# Java Axis2 Web Service calling JAX-WS client jar

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have an Axis2 (1.5.1) Web Service deployed on Tomcat 6, and I am trying to call the VMware Web Services SDK (JAX-WS service). This fails since the I need to maintain sessions (SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY = true). Is there any way to circumvent Axis2 when calling the JAX-WS client jar?

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error: Maintain Session is enabled but none of the session properties (Cookies, Over-written URL) are returned.
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.BindingProvider.setupSessionContext(BindingProvider.java:242)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.BindingProvider.checkMaintainSessionState(BindingProvider.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:320)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:159)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.retrieveServiceContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.product.CredAuthHostSkeleton.getAuthKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.product.CredAuthHostMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem turned out to be threefold. The first issue was an out-of-date Axis2 version (1.5.1), and the other two issues were code based.

**Solution**

After upgrading the Axis version to the latest version (went from 1.5.1 to 1.7.4), the following code changes fixed the issue:

1. Since Axis2 expects the name of the session cookie to be JSESSIONID and VMware returns vmware_soap_session, the CUSTOM_COOKIE_ID property need to be set so that Axis2 detects that the session cookie is set.

   ```
   VimService vimService = new VimService();
   VimPortType vimPort = vimService.getVimPort();

   Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider)vimPort).getRequestContext();
   ctxt.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url.toString());
   ctxt.put(org.apache.axis2.Constants.CUSTOM_COOKIE_ID, "vmware_soap_session");
   ctxt.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
   ```
2. When Axis2 maintains sessions, it expects the first call to set the session cookie. The first call to the VMware API to retrieve the service content does not need a session, so it doesn't return a cookie. The solution here was to add another VimService and VimPortType to be used exclusively for retrieving the service content. After these changes the login call will work.

   ```
   VimService vimServiceRSC = new VimService();
   VimPortType vimPortRSC = vimService.getVimPort();

   Map<String, Object> ctxtRSC = ((BindingProvider)vimPortRSC).getRequestContext();
   ctxtRSC.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url.toString());

   ServiceContent serviceContent = vimPortRSC.retrieveServiceContent(this.getServiceInstanceRef());
   vimPort.login(serviceContent.getSessionManager(), "user", "password", null);
   ```

*The code changes are shown using snippets of the sample code provided with the VMware SDK.*